# How to change component when click on button angular

Tags: angular, angular8

I am trying to create this dashboard and i want to know how to change one component when a menu link is clicked?
[image: This is dashboard]

I split it in 3 components like that

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <app-dashboard-menu></app-dashboard-menu>
  <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div id="content">
      <app-dashboard-topbar></app-dashboard-topbar>
      <app-dashboard-content></app-dashboard-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i want to be know how can i add (onclick) to a menu item and change from  to lets say  and keep the same layout. Just to be able to change only dashboard content to any other component i create

Answer (score 5):

if you already had finished routing, add this property into html button tag

```
<button type="button"  routerLink="/content">Content</button>
```

or, add like this in component.ts

```
<button type="button" (click)="btnClick()">Content</button>    

import { Router } from '@angular/router';

btnClick() {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/content');
};
```

Comment: Thanks but i used router outlet and declared them as children of the dashboard component

Comment: yeah, also the router outlet need is need for my answer. sorry, I couldn't mention it before